# Stopping a jquery animation within step, then setting the animated property

Tags: jquery, animation, queue

I'm animating a block moving around and am using the step option to check at every step if a boolean has been switched to true. If it does get switched, I want to stop the animation and set the property I was animating to a certain value. Here's the code I have right now

```
$("#block").animate( { bottom: "+=128" },
{ duration:200,
easing: "easeOutCubic",
step: function(){
        if( stopped == true ){
            $("#block").stop().css("bottom", "none");
            $("#block").css("bottom", "5px");
            //setTimeout( function(){ $("#block").css("bottom", "5px"); }, 1);
        }
    },
complete: function(){
        //complete function
    }
}
```

);

If I delay the code for even 1 millisecond (the commented line), it works. I'm willing to use that if there isn't another way, but I'm more interested in knowing why setting the css property doesn't work within the step option, but does work within the timeout function. Or if I'm just missing something basic here. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I found out the problem, but don't know how to fix it. May be this will be usefull:
Jquery has 
`function Animation( elem, properties, options )` which has function `tick` and there is cycle in that function 
`for ( ; index < length ; index++ ) {
    animation.tweens[ index ].run( percent );
}`. Line 8687 http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js
So when animation is stopped and `.css('bottom', '5px')` executed this cycle works one more and animate one last step, so css bottom changes.
Also I tried to play with animation queue, but useless((

Comment: Wow, awesome. I figured that it had to be something that the function was executing. I think for the time being I'll have to use the timeout because every thing that I've tried to get around it hasn't worked either.

Comment: I think this is the dirty fix but it is the simplest and fastest way. If I find a way to solve this, I'll tell you

Comment: Update: I'm no longer using the timer method, but instead am animating a dummy object set to display:none and using the step function's now value to animate a separate object that follows along. In the step function, if it's over the value, the second object doesn't move. It's still a little bit of a dirty fix, but visually is more appealing and doesn't use timers (I hate timers)

Answer (score 1):

Late answer but I worked out how to stop your animate from within a step.

Simply use `$(this).stop()`. Then you can set the final property:

```
$("#block").animate( { bottom: "+=128" }, {
    duration:200,
    easing: "easeOutCubic",
    step: function(now, fx) {

        if( stopped == true ) {

            $(this).stop();

            $("#block").css("bottom", "none");
            $("#block").css("bottom", "5px");

        }
    },
    complete: function() {
        //complete function
    }
}
```